# Access app.config values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, app-config

I need to fill a variable with a value from the app.config. Is there a way to do this in Javascript? This is what I have right now, however I don't believe it's in any way correct..

```
var notConfident = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleValue"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, javascript runs in the client side browser, the app config is a file in the server.

You can get the value by sending it to the client side, something like:

.aspx file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ikey" runat="server" />
```

.cs file, page load method:

```
ikey.InnerText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleValue"];
```

.js file, onload method:

```
var something = document.getElementById("ikey").value;
```